# Does passing a vector reference transfer ownership of its data?

Tags: c++, rvo

What is the best way of passing and transferring ownership of a vector and it's data?

In an ideal world, it would work something like this:

```
std::vector<int>& SpitAVector(int input)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    result.push_back(input);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myvec;
    myvec = SpitAVector(60);

    std::cout << (int)myvec[0] << std::endl;  //Outputs 60      
}
```

This doesn't work, since I'm returning a reference to a local variable.

Is it possible to use `boost::unique_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr` to handle this vector output? (Can't use C++11's unique_ptr!)

Comment: Why don't you just return it by value? Any decent optimizing compiler will optimize the copy to a move.

Comment: Any conforming C++11 compiler will do only a move at most. Any decent optimizing compiler will elide the copy/move altogether.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Actually, RVO will simply construct the vector where it would be returned to, so there won't even be a move with any modern compiler.

Comment: @cdhowie yep, yet another reason to just return it by-value.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3134831/332733

Answer (score 5):

> What is the best way of passing and transferring ownership of a vector and it's data?

Return the vector by value.

In C++11 or later, the return value will be moved (if necessary), so there certainly won't be a bulk data copy.

If you're stuck in the past, then make sure you meet the criteria for *copy elision* of the return value. Your function, with a single return point, does. Although it's not required to, any decent compiler will perform that optimisation.

> Is it possible to use boost::unique_ptr or boost::shared_ptr to handle this vector output?

Yes, but that would be unnecessarily complicated. Just return by value.

Comment: This vector should hold about 260 MB of data. I'm assuming returning by value won't cause a copy then

Comment: @Daniel: It won't if you're using C++11 (with move semantics), or have a single return point (as you do here). I'm just writing some details about that.

Comment: @Daniel Most compilers these days implement return value optimization (RVO), which will cause the vector to be constructed in the stack space of the calling function where it would be returned to -- there won't be a copy-construction, nor even a move-construction.