# Is it better to use pass by reference to fill a container or use the return value to fill it instead?

Tags: c++, c++11

Sorry for the confusing title, and sorry if this is a duplicate (I tried searching for an answer online), hopefully this example clears it up:

Basically, would it be better to do this:

```
void fill(vector<int> & v);

int main() {
  vector<int> v;
  fill(v);
  return 0;
}
```

or this:

```
vector<int> fill();

int main() {
  vector<int> v = fill();
  return 0;
}
```

I've been reading about how in C++11 the compiler will move the return results of functions rather than copying them. Is one of these better than the other? Or is it simply preference?

Comment: You just use std::move and you will be fine but better to use reference.

Comment: In the first example, do you really mean `const`? How can `fill()` modify a `const vector<int>&`?

Comment: Some insightful answers to a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134831/in-c-is-it-still-bad-practice-to-return-a-vector-from-a-function

Comment: Useful discussion: https://blog.knatten.org/2011/08/26/dont-be-afraid-of-returning-by-value-know-the-return-value-optimization/ https://web.archive.org/web/20130930101140/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value

Comment: sorry about the const, that was a typo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the perspective of [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) it is better to use return value for modifying an variable.

For example if you have a `fill()` function that creates initial configuration for a vector, the function's responsibility is to create initial configurations(read them from db, file or just hard-coded configuration). Not assign the configuration to your variable(that might be also a complex process).

And if you are going to change only 1 variable, it increments the readability of the code. You don't need to remember if the `fill()` function modifies your variable or not.

Comment: you are taking that principal to an extreme, that way operator += also violates it..

Comment: we don't know what fill() does, as i said fill function may be accessing db, file or some other resource to gather information then fill the variable. += only assigns a value to variable, i wouldn't complain about string s = "foo bar"; s += s.substring(1,3); because substring only cares about taking substring of a string.

Answer (score -1):

The former is better as it avoids a copy operation at the end . But I rather prefer this :

```
  bool fill(vector<int> & v);
```

The return flag is used to identify if the function was executed successfully.

Comment: With return value optimization, it seems unlikely that `fill()` would have a "copy operation at the end".